# Updating the kerberors krb.conf file using "java.security.krb5.conf" System.property() is not working

Tags: java, kerberos, jaas, java.security

I want to point to a **different krb.conf file**, `dynamically, without restarting the JVM`. I have searched through different solution on Stackoverflow and tried to implement the solution accordingly. But some how, even **if I update the System.property("java.security.krb5.conf", ...)** to point the `the new krb.conf file`, the JAAS is not able to understand this and still using the earlier conf file. Following are the details of my solution with the code:

My Jaas.conf file is as follows:

```
   Mutual {
      com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required client=TRUE;
   };
   sp.kerb.sso.KinitExample {
      com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required 
      client=TRUE 
      refreshKrb5Config=true
      debug=true;
  };
```

I have set `refreshKrb5Config=true` for obvious reasons as I want to reload the krb configuration file.

Here is the code I am trying to execute:
package sp.kerb.sso;

```
import sun.security.krb5.internal.tools.Kinit;

public class KinitExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {

      String kerberosFileName = "C:\\Windows\\krb5.ini";
      String jaas_config_file_name = "C:\\Users\\User1\\temp\\howrah.jaas.conf";

      System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", jaas_config_file_name);  // setting the jaas config file
      System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf"        , kerberosFileName); // setting the kerberos file
      System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.debug"        , "true");

      final String administrator = "admin@exampledomain.lab".toUpperCase();
      String cacheFileLoc = "C:\\Users\\User1\\temp\\admin.cache";

      // Perfoming Kinit ...
      Kinit.main(new String[]{"-c",cacheFileLoc, administrator , "Password123" });

      kerberosFileName = "C:\\Users\\User2\\temp\\new.krb.conf";    // Using new KRB configuration file

      System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.debug"        , "true");
      System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", jaas_config_file_name); // setting the property again
      
      System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf"        , kerberosFileName); // setting the property again

      System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.security.krb5.conf")); // Prints the updated conf file location.

      cacheFileLoc = "C:\\Users\\User2\\temp\\newadmin.cache";
      String newAdmin = "administrator@test.lab".toUpperCase();
      Kinit.main(new String[]{"-c",cacheFileLoc, newAdmin , "Password123" });
    }
 }
```

The cache for the `admin` is **created**, but the cache for the `newAdmin` is not **created** as the respective krb.conf files have distinct realms and JAAS doesn't seem to able to connect to the realm from the **new.krb.conf** and hence fails with the infamour 906 error code.

What is it that I am doing wrong? What I want to achieve is possible? How should I resolve the issue?

---

Also Note that, if I totally comment the admin cache creation logic and start with the new.krb.conf (all the code related to newAdmin) it works perfectly fine and creates the cache for the newAdmin

Comment: _"krb.conf files have distinct realms "_ >> do you have a good reason not to **merge** these files? I mean, in large multinational corporations I have seen 10+ Kerberos realms _(AD domains actually)_ listed, with cross-realm authentication enabled _(implicitly via the "root" domain/realm)_. Sometimes with a specific realm _(MIT Kerberos or FreeIPA)_ servicing a specific Hadoop cluster, on top of that.

Comment: The reason for different krb.conf files is that, our application works as a middle layer to fetch/search the AD objects from the AD domains. We don't know which AD domains to handle beforehand to create a single/static krb.conf file

Comment: Two things to try out: 1. raise some JAAS debuging flags i.e. `-Djava.security.debug=gssloginconfig,configfile,configparser‌​,logincontext` -- configuration issues are silently ignored, the flags are the only way to detect them // 2. reset the JAAS configuration with e.g. a different file name and see if the Kerberos conf is bounced also

Comment: And then 3. change dynamically the _content_ of the _initial_ krb5.conf and see what happens

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should call `sun.security.krb5.Config.refresh();` in order to reload configuration from new file.

Comment: Oh man, that was a godsent answer!